# PDF::API2: set PDF tags

Tags: perl, pdf, pdf-generation, accessibility, perl-module

Does anybody know how can one set PDF tags using [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.020/lib/PDF/API2.pm) perl module?

Is it related to the following subroutine:

```
@attributes = $pdf->infoMetaAttributes('CustomField1');
print "Supported Attributes: @attributes\n";
```

Any reference how to do this with this Perl module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDF::API2 (I think that's what you meant to type), the **info** method allows you to obtain and modify the PDF tags.  The **infoMetaAttributes** is used to obtain or modify the list of possible tags themselves, not to provide values for one or more of them.

So, to set the author to "Fred":

```
$pdf->info ('Author' => 'Fred');
```

To find the current author:

```
my $author = $pdf->info ('Author');
```

To show 'em all:

```
my %tags = $pdf->info;
for my $tag (keys %tags) {
    print $tag, " has value ", $tags{$tag}
}
```